# Creating a new column and adding a value in a specified row using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like create a new column my dataset and insert a value in a specific row based ona few conditions.

I found this previous post that was helpful but it does not account for multiple conditions, just name == Tim. [How to create a new column and insert value at a particular row in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864822/how-to-create-a-new-column-and-insert-value-at-a-particular-row-in-pandas-datafr)

DF:

| Date | Group | State | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 001 | IL | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 002 | IL | 5 |
| 2021-01-02 | 001 | CA | 3 |
| 2021-01-02 | 002 | CA | 9 |
| 2021-01-03 | 001 | AZ | 2 |
| 2021-01-03 | 002 | AZ | 8 |
| 2021-01-04 | 001 | WY | 4 |
| 2021-01-04 | 002 | WY | 7 |

Desired Output:

DF:

| Date | Group | State | Count | Sub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 001 | IL | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 002 | IL | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 001 | CA | 3 | 0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 002 | CA | 9 | 0 |
| 2021-01-03 | 001 | AZ | 2 | 0 |
| 2021-01-03 | 002 | AZ | 8 | 3 |
| 2021-01-04 | 001 | WY | 4 | 0 |
| 2021-01-04 | 002 | WY | 7 | 0 |

I would like insert the value '3' where Date == 2021-01-03 and group = 002 and state = 'AZ'.

EDIT: I cannot use the post that was linked to this question because the rows of this dataframe are updated everyday. As such, I need it to pinpoint the exact day, group, and state, not just the row number.

Solution found:

```
df.loc[(df['Date'] == '2021-01-03') & (df['Group'] == '002') & (df['State'] == 'AZ'), 'Sub'] = 3
```

Any help would be appreciated.